# How to search definitelytyped file version via npm?

Tags: typescript2.0, definitelytyped

I've using TypeScript for a long time. But now I confuse how to search definitelytyped. When I was using tsd, typings until now via npm using @types, I could command in **typings search jasmine** and return a list I could pick the version that I want. But in TypeScript 2.0 version using @type via npm to get .d.ts file. I didn't know how to determine which version that I want.

Answer (score 1):

got it. use **yarn info @types/jasmine** will give you the list of versions. Then **yarn add @types/jasmine@1.3.0** will work.

Comment: I assume you want to add this as a development dependency, e.g. `yarn add @types/jasmine@1.3.0 --dev`.